# Where are all the builtin macros defined in clang?

Tags: clang

I see that `__GNUC__` is availble in clang, but they are not found here. Is there a place that has a complete list of all builtin macros in clang?

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any macros defined by `clang` can be found with this command:

```
clang -dM -E -x c /dev/null
```

And any macros defined by `clang++` can be found by this command:

```
clang++ -dM -E -x c++ /dev/null
```

Reference: [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20180826223211/http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2011/12/c_c_tip_how_list_compiler_predefined_macros) link

Comment: I don't see `__GNUC__` on that page.

Comment: This isn't *all* the builtin macros though. It is missing, *inter alia*, `__BASE_FILE__`, `__COUNTER__`, `__DATE__`, `__FILE__`, `__INCLUDE_LEVEL__`, `__LINE__`, `__TIMESTAMP__`, `__TIME__`. The most complete source for this info, is reading the clang source code, see in particular https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/llvmorg-15.0.2/clang/lib/Lex/PPMacroExpansion.cpp#L339